# When are lambda function call operators instantiated?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Suppose a non-generic lambda appears within a templated entity, as in the code below:

```
template <class T, auto F = [](T x) { *x; }>
void foo(T t) {}

void foo(...) {}

int main() {
    foo(42);
}
```

[[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#2) is relevant here:

> The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding *lambda-expression*. [...]

Therefore, during substitution into `foo<int>`, a lambda closure type is declared in global scope, and its function call operator is not a template. That lambda closure type is a templated entity ([[temp.pre]/8.5](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre#8.5)), and therefore so is its function call operator ([temp.pre]/8.3). But the latter is neither a function template specialization, nor a member of a class template specialization, for which implicit instantiation would occur as described in [[temp.inst]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#5).

The most straightforward reading is that the lambda function call operator in the above code is not subject to as-needed instantiation; it is simply defined at the same time as the closure type. This appears to be consistent with GCC rejecting the above code. Another possible interpretation is that it is intended to be instantiated as needed like a function template specialization and there is an oversight in the wording; this would make the above code well-formed, with `foo<int>` being called. Clang seems to disagree with both interpretations; it calls `foo(...)`, as if the other overload were subject to a substitution failure in the immediate context (which seems wrong to me; lambda expressions are not in the immediate context).

Comment: This bug in Clang is fixed now: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/61889

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After mulling this over, I believe GCC is correct. The meaning of instantiation of a templated entity should, by default, be considered to include the instantiation of any entity it encloses, other than one that is still dependent after the nearest enclosing entity is instantiated. For example, in

```
template <class T>
T foo(T t) {
    return t + 1;
}
```

we don't need an explicit rule in the standard that says that when `foo` is instantiated, the `return` statement in its body is also instantiated. That's implicit.

That's also why the standard merely has a [note](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#note-3) stating that a local class, and the members of a local class, are not subject to separate instantiation from the function definition whose scope they belong to. Notes are non-normative, so a note such as this merely serves to point out a consequence of the normative rules. Because a local class's definition, and the definition of each of its members, occurs lexically within the function definition, it is already implicit that all such enclosed definitions are instantiated when the function definition is.

There are various exceptions enumerated in [temp.inst] to the general rule; the default arguments of a function are not instantiated as part of the instantiation of the function declaration or definition in which they lexically occur, for example ([[temp.inst]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#5)). Because there is no such exception for a *lambda-expression* (or the members of a *lambda-expression*) that is lexically within an enclosing templated entity, the *lambda-expression* and the definition of its closure type and the closure type's `operator()` must be instantiated as part of the instantiation of the nearest enclosing templated entity, at which point the *lambda-expression* and its closure type are no longer dependent. If it is a generic lambda, its `operator()` is a function template and its instantiation is deferred until required by [temp.inst]/5; if it is a non-generic lambda, then it is no longer dependent and is instantiated immediately.